# How To Make Custom Alert Dialog on Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to make custom alert dialog with different style. As we know, that the default style is square. I want make it like on candy crush game if you ever seen. I've try to change the background style, but the default background still appear. this is my xml file for my dialog layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/dialog" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivPic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/svAlert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivPic"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"/>
</ScrollView>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bOKE"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/svAlert"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

could you help me please?
Thanks before...

Comment: ...and how do you use it?

Comment: @user3503360 do you have any image for sample?

Answer (score 0):

First, set a custom theme with your background image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then,set the theme to your dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme));
```

Comment: I have been doing this creating a custom layout all the time. I vl try n if this works, u are the mahn.

Comment: I mean custom theme,not custom layout.

Comment: where I should place this code? I named my layout with "my_alert.xml".
should I insert your code on it?

Comment: Use `LayoutInflater.inflate(my_alert.xml) ` get the `View`,then set the dialog's view with `dialog.setView()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have specify a background to your AlertDialog's layout. You should make the default windowBackground to disappear. So change `android:windowBackground` of your dialog to transparent:

```
<style name="YourDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
  ...
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```